# How to store user data once user login with Facebook/Google account on my website

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website where I store user info like user id, email , password, and some other info once user registered, where user Id is auto generated field in DB with Auto Increment method in MySQL.

Now I want to implement Facebook & Google Login. Facebook & Google gives very long user id(20 to 36 char long) once we make the request to there api but I can store max 6 char long user Id.

So I want to know what is the best way to store it. Shall I create a new table where I can create mapping with FB/G+ user id to my User's table user id and every time user login I check this mapping table and get user id created by my DB corresponding to FB/G+ user id and perform all the operation using my user Id OR shall I store FB/G+ user id directly to my User table but for this we need to change Table structure and many table because user id is FK for many tables

Comment: You can add columns to your existing table as `facebook_user_id`, `google_user_id` with desired storage. Rest all the fields I think will be common `email` , `password`. Don't use  `facebook_user_id`, `google_user_id` other than login functionality. Use your autogenerated surrogate primary key `user_id` for all relations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this approach looks good

Comment: I f you have liked the approach, can you please upvote?

Comment: i can't upvote my question